# In IE9, the pseudo-element :after on a TD doesn't get the correct TD height, is there a fix for this?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, pseudo-element

The design I'm working with requires a border around a table row. For other complicated reasons, I cannot use the border property directly to achieve this. I have tried 2 approached, both involving using the pseudo-element :after.

1. I used a `tr:after`. This works in all browsers except for IE8+. IE does not render the styles specified under `tr:after` at all.
2. I also tried `td:after`. This time the border shows up in IE8+, but IE doesn't render the border around the full height of the td, despite what the CSS says.

http://jsfiddle.net/kxmhW/2/ Please have a look and let me know if there is a way to fix this. The first table in the link uses tr:after. The second table uses `td:after`.

Thank you.

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. Other than that, I'm not sure how to fix this...

Comment: You're right, sorry for the error in language.

Comment: You are just trying to get borders around the rows correct?

Comment: Yes, but there is already another border applied to the tr element. The design has multiple borders.

Comment: What about using outline?  It is similar to border (`outline: 1px solid blue`), but you can use it along side existing borders.  I don't think it exists in IE8, but at least it won't have the disjointed border look you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get borders around the rows, would something like this work for your situation?

**CSS**

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
background: #ddd;
width: 100px;
}

.tr-border  tr {
border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="tr-border">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>123,456</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>$10.24</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consect EturLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>123,456</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>$10.24</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consect EturLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <br />

  <table class="tr-border">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>123,456</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>$10.24</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consect EturLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>123,456</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>$10.24</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consect EturLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/kxmhW/30/

Comment: I wish this worked, but there is already a border specified on the tr. The design has multiple borders. I suppose this is more what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/kxmhW/31/

Comment: Okay I see.. Also... I don't think it is the issue, but :last-child doesn't work in IE8 or older...

Comment: Well you got me on this one... And I don't have to much time to look into it further... My advice would be to design to web standards..